# Modify User Active Directory Domain during Login

Tags: login, credentials, directory

We currently have two domains which I'll call DomainOld and DomainNew. We have users whose machines are set to use DomainOld and won't be pushed to DomainNew for at least a year. Each user has an account of the same name in both DomainOld and DomainNew. I am trying to grab the login name that is automatically passed, check to see if it is DomainOld and if it is, modify it to use DomainNew\Username and pass the user through to SharePoint.

We ARE using Windows Authentication. We are NOT using Claims or FBA.

Is there a way to do this? Basically, I'm trying to override the username passed in. If they pass in just Username, I want to append DomainNew\ in front. If they pass in DomainOld\Usernamer, I want to replace DomainOld with DomainNew so they are logged in under the new domain. The DomainOld will be retired in about one year, but we don't want things created on SharePoint under DomainOld.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

John